# Finding the left (or right) ideals of the ring of $n\times n$ matrices

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> Just give me a hint, since this is assessment! DO NOT TELL ME THE IDEAL

I want to find the left (or right) ideals of the ring of $n\times n$ complex valued matrices.

Now the definition is (for left ideals):

A subset $I$ of $R$ is called a left ideal of $R$ if it is an additive subgroup of $R$ absorbing multiplication on the left:

$$(I,+) \text{ is a subgroup of } (R,+)$$
$$\forall x \in I, \forall r\in R:\quad r\cdot x \in I$$

Now my problem is: We don't start with any element of $I$ from the definition, so we can't iteratively determine the ideal. So my next assumption is guessing at the ideal. Let the ideal be the entire group. Then clearly $r\cdot r \in I$. So then the left ideal is equal to the whole ring. Where is my idea wrong?

Comment: Hint: The rows of $rx$ are linear combinations of rows of $x$. You get all such combinations with an appropriate choice of $r$.

Comment: You just assumed that the ideal is the entire ring and verified that,The entire ring is always a left ideal, but there are others... and that's where the interesting game takes place. With right ideals think in terms of column spaces instead.

Comment: Ahhh for some reason I believed there was only 1 left ideal, or 1 right ideal. This makes much more sense